# How to put Javascripts for evaluation in evaluatejavascript function of QWebView

Tags: javascript, qt, google-maps, qwebview

EDIT:
Too many edits :doh:

I have identified the problem this time. There is a flaw in the way I am passing the Javascript code to the evaluatejavascript func. of QWebView.

Using Google maps's API, when I click a pushButton attached to the slot holding the below code

`this->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript (QString ("Open(%1,2)").arg ( point.x ()).arg (point.y ()) );`

the map pertaining to the location in question gets displayed.

Now if I want to add a marker to a particular coordinate, I do:

```
this->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript (QString ("addMarker (%1, %2)").arg (point.x ()).arg (point.y ()) );
```

This code doesn't execute. Any ideas?

Besides this, what is the way to add a **user defined** function to **evaluateJavaScript** for evaluation?

Comment: @Anisha: From what I see you're not printing an error code but just the address of your QNetworkReply? If you get a NULL from your call to get(), then something is wrong. Now it properly returns a new QNetworkReply object it seems. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: @Bart Now I added the code `QNetworkReply *h = manager->get (QNetworkRequest (QUrl (hh)));
 
 if (h->error() == 0)
 {
  cout << "NO ERROR";
 }
 else
 {
  cout << hex << "ERROR: " << h << dec;
 }` and NO ERROR gets printed, but still the doesn't get displayed!

Comment: Nothing gets displayed? Not even your "loadcoor" string to cout?

Comment: The "loadcoor" string gets displayed after I close the map window :banghead:

Comment: Can you change that line to `cout << "\nloadcoor" << std::endl;` and see if it prints earlier? I also see that you're not setting an API key in `geoCode()`? Not sure if this is necessary to make it work though. But now your `key` argument is empty.

Comment: Thanks for being around Bart :) Now that loadcoor IS printed, but NO map still! The key is missing because I am not doing all this on a website. I loading the map on a qt widget only. This link asks for a website address: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html What to do?

Comment: Also, I feel the Javascript is not doing its job, since when I use the simple load() function, the map gets displayed.

Comment: I simply have no experience with the Google Maps API and whether or not a key is needed. So I can't help you with that unfortunately. Perhaps you could verify that the string you assemble looks correct. Can't be of more help I'm afraid. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer!

Any Javascript function which has to be called from function **evaluateJavaScript** is supposed to be defined in an html file (included in) the C++ source, as shown below:

Now instead of creating a new add marker function, I have added its code in the Open function defined below:

```
var map;

function initialize()
{
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
      {
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.setCenter( new GLatLng(0,0),1 );
      }
    }

function Open (x,y)
{
    map.setCenter (new GLatLng(x,y), 13);

    var point = new GLatLng (x,y);
    map.addOverlay (new GMarker(point));
}
```